# Can I use a third party slider on my BigCommerce home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, bigcommerce

I'm trying to customize my BigCommerce home page. So, I'd like to use a third party slider which is rather nicer more than inbuilt BigCommerce default slider.

So, I placed the third party slider on the home page and placed the necessary files on the directory. (Actually, I didn't know how to place them on the same directory. Such as following

```
"/images/slider.js"
```

Instead, I placed them on a different directory. Like this,

```
http://mydomain.com/templates/externalslider/slider.js
```

The problem is the slider takes an unusual time to load on the page and does not slide. It just loads the first slide and appears the loading symbol. Then nothing.

Does anybody know what's wrong with it ?

I'm pretty sure I included all the necessary files. ( I tried this on a different server on a static page. It worked fine. )

Not working only on the BigCommerce page.

I appreciate your help....

Thanks..

Comment: Please post your code and the url of the site (if possible).

Comment: Thanks for replying Louis. Actually, it's not just a single piece of code. I can paste it here but it's very long. scripts codes, css codes, and HTML code. So, where should I start with ? Can yoiu just give me a clue ? Have you ever experienced something like this ? I saw you've over 1000 reputation. So, it means you're well matured in this field :-)

Comment: Hm, I can try. Are you getting any errors in your developer console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your file paths are wrong. Typically a Bigcommerce file path will look more like the following:

```
/templates/__custom/images/yourimages.jpg
```

Of course it would be helpful if you posted a link.